# I am using ag-grid enterprise licensed controls and want to use ag-grid BarSparklines inside grid cells

Tags: angular, ag-grid, sparklines

I had followed every step of ag-grid documentation as stated in link below:

https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/sparklines-bar-customisation/

**My grid cells definition is as follows:**

```
this.immediatecolumnDefs = 
[
      {
        field: 'ncrdetail',
        headerName: 'NCR Detail',
        sortable: true,
        resizable: true,
        filter: true,
      },  
      {
        field: 'product',
        headerName: 'Product Description',
        sortable: true,
        resizable: true,
        filter: true,
      },
      {
        field: 'totalholdqty',
        headerName: 'Total Hold Qty',
        sortable: true,
        resizable: true,
        filter: true,
      },
      {
        field: 'holdqty',
        headerName: 'Balance Qty',
        hide: true,
        // sortable: true,
        // resizable: true,
        // filter: true,
      },
      {
        field: 'ncrdate',
        headerName: 'NCR Date',
        sortable: true,
        resizable: true,
        filter: true,
      },
      {
        field: 'status',
        headerName: 'Status',
        sortable: true,
        resizable: true,
        filter: true,
      },
      {
        field: 'sorting',
        cellRenderer: 'agSparklineCellRenderer',
        cellRendererParams: {
          sparklineOptions: {
            type: 'bar',
            fill: '#5470c6',
            stroke: '#91cc75',
            highlightStyle: {
              fill: 'orange', // sets the highlighted bar fill
            },
            valueAxisDomain: [0, 1],
            paddingOuter: 0,
            padding: {
              top: 0,
              bottom: 0,
            },
            axis: {
              strokeWidth: 0,
            },
          } as BarSparklineOptions,
        },
      },
      {
        field: 'reprocess',
        cellRenderer: 'agSparklineCellRenderer',
        cellRendererParams: {
          sparklineOptions: {
            type: 'bar',
            fill: '#5470c6',
            stroke: '#91cc75',
            highlightStyle: {
              fill: '#fac858',
            },
            valueAxisDomain: [0, 1],
            paddingOuter: 0,
            padding: {
              top: 0,
              bottom: 0,
            },
            axis: {
              strokeWidth: 0,
            },
          } as BarSparklineOptions,
        },
      },
      {
        field: 'concession',
        cellRenderer: 'agSparklineCellRenderer',
        cellRendererParams: {
          sparklineOptions: {
            type: 'bar',
            fill: '#5470c6',
            stroke: '#91cc75',
            highlightStyle: {
              fill: '#fac858',
            },
            valueAxisDomain: [0, 1],
            paddingOuter: 0,
            padding: {
              top: 0,
              bottom: 0,
            },
            axis: {
              strokeWidth: 0,
            },
          } as BarSparklineOptions,
        },
      },
      {
        field: 'downgrade',
        cellRenderer: 'agSparklineCellRenderer',
        cellRendererParams: {
          sparklineOptions: {
            type: 'bar',
            fill: '#5470c6',
            stroke: '#91cc75',
            highlightStyle: {
              fill: '#fac858',
            },
            valueAxisDomain: [0, 1],
            paddingOuter: 0,
            padding: {
              top: 0,
              bottom: 0,
            },
            axis: {
              strokeWidth: 0,
            },
          } as BarSparklineOptions,
        },
      },
      {
        field: 'dispose',
        cellRenderer: 'agSparklineCellRenderer',
        cellRendererParams: {
          sparklineOptions: {
            type: 'bar',
            fill: '#5470c6',
            stroke: '#91cc75',
            highlightStyle: {
              fill: '#fac858',
            },
            valueAxisDomain: [0, 1],
            paddingOuter: 0,
            padding: {
              top: 0,
              bottom: 0,
            },
            axis: {
              strokeWidth: 0,
            },
          } as BarSparklineOptions,
        },
      },
      {
        field: 'action',
        headerName: 'Action',
        sortable: true,
        resizable: true,
        filter: 
        true,
        cellRenderer: (): any => {
          return `
            <button mat-mini-fab="" color="warn" ptooltip="Action History" tooltipposition="top" class="mat-focus-indicator mat-mini-fab mat-button-base mat-primary" style="background-color: #7a1dcf;" ng-reflect-color="primary" ng-reflect-text="Action Detail" ng-reflect-tooltip-position="top"><span class="mat-button-wrapper"><i class="fa fa-list" style="color: #fff;"></i></span><span matripple="" class="mat-ripple mat-button-ripple mat-button-ripple-round" ng-reflect-disabled="false" ng-reflect-centered="false" ng-reflect-trigger="[object HTMLButtonElement]"></span><span class="mat-button-focus-overlay"></span></button>
            `;
        },
        cellRendererParams: {
          clicked(field: any): any {},
        },
      },
    ];
```

**Data which I am passing is given below:**

```
this.immediaterowData = [
          { id:0, ncrdate:'2022-02-26 18:26:00', ncrdetail:'', status:'test', product:'test',  totalholdqty:5000, sorting:[0.1,0.9], reprocess:[0.5,0.5], concession:[0.4,0.6], downgrade:[0.2,0.8], dispose:[0.3,0.7]},
          { id:0, ncrdate:'2022-enter code here02-26 18:26:00', ncrdetail:'', status:'test', product:'test',  totalholdqty:5000, sorting:[0.1,0.9], reprocess:[0.5,0.5], concession:[0.4,0.6], downgrade:[0.2,0.8], dispose:[0.3,0.7]},
          { id:0, ncrdate:'2022-02-26 18:26:00', ncrdetail:'', status:'test', product:'test',  totalholdqty:5000, sorting:[0.1,0.9], reprocess:[0.5,0.5], concession:[0.4,0.6], downgrade:[0.2,0.8], dispose:[0.3,0.7]}
        ];
```

**I want bars in sorting, reprocess, concession, downgrade and dispose columns but i am receiving it like this:**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmSZz.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your code works when I use it in as a plunker based on the first example of the AG Grid documentation you provided.

https://plnkr.co/edit/ZV7CpSmBiYtSPmIv

Are you completely sure you are using the enterprise version of AG Grid?

```js
function getData() {
  return [
          { id:0, ncrdate:'2022-02-26 18:26:00', ncrdetail:'', status:'test', product:'test',  totalholdqty:5000, sorting:[0.1,0.9], reprocess:[0.5,0.5], concession:[0.4,0.6], downgrade:[0.2,0.8], dispose:[0.3,0.7]},
          { id:0, ncrdate:'2022-enter code here02-26 18:26:00', ncrdetail:'', status:'test', product:'test',  totalholdqty:5000, sorting:[0.1,0.9], reprocess:[0.5,0.5], concession:[0.4,0.6], downgrade:[0.2,0.8], dispose:[0.3,0.7]},
          { id:0, ncrdate:'2022-02-26 18:26:00', ncrdetail:'', status:'test', product:'test',  totalholdqty:5000, sorting:[0.1,0.9], reprocess:[0.5,0.5], concession:[0.4,0.6], downgrade:[0.2,0.8], dispose:[0.3,0.7]}
        ];
}

const gridOptions = {
  columnDefs: [
      {
        field: 'ncrdetail',
        headerName: 'NCR Detail',
        sortable: true,
        resizable: true,
        filter: true,
      },  
      {
        field: 'product',
        headerName: 'Product Description',
        sortable: true,
        resizable: true,
        filter: true,
      },
      {
        field: 'totalholdqty',
        headerName: 'Total Hold Qty',
        sortable: true,
        resizable: true,
        filter: true,
      },
      {
        field: 'holdqty',
        headerName: 'Balance Qty',
        hide: true,
        // sortable: true,
        // resizable: true,
        // filter: true,
      },
      {
        field: 'ncrdate',
        headerName: 'NCR Date',
        sortable: true,
        resizable: true,
        filter: true,
      },
      {
        field: 'status',
        headerName: 'Status',
        sortable: true,
        resizable: true,
        filter: true,
      },
      {
        field: 'sorting',
        cellRenderer: 'agSparklineCellRenderer',
        cellRendererParams: {
          sparklineOptions: {
            type: 'bar',
            fill: '#5470c6',
            stroke: '#91cc75',
            highlightStyle: {
              fill: 'orange', // sets the highlighted bar fill
            },
            valueAxisDomain: [0, 1],
            paddingOuter: 0,
            padding: {
              top: 0,
              bottom: 0,
            },
            axis: {
              strokeWidth: 0,
            },
          },
        },
      },
      {
        field: 'reprocess',
        cellRenderer: 'agSparklineCellRenderer',
        cellRendererParams: {
          sparklineOptions: {
            type: 'bar',
            fill: '#5470c6',
            stroke: '#91cc75',
            highlightStyle: {
              fill: '#fac858',
            },
            valueAxisDomain: [0, 1],
            paddingOuter: 0,
            padding: {
              top: 0,
              bottom: 0,
            },
            axis: {
              strokeWidth: 0,
            },
          },
        },
      },
      {
        field: 'concession',
        cellRenderer: 'agSparklineCellRenderer',
        cellRendererParams: {
          sparklineOptions: {
            type: 'bar',
            fill: '#5470c6',
            stroke: '#91cc75',
            highlightStyle: {
              fill: '#fac858',
            },
            valueAxisDomain: [0, 1],
            paddingOuter: 0,
            padding: {
              top: 0,
              bottom: 0,
            },
            axis: {
              strokeWidth: 0,
            },
          },
        },
      },
      {
        field: 'downgrade',
        cellRenderer: 'agSparklineCellRenderer',
        cellRendererParams: {
          sparklineOptions: {
            type: 'bar',
            fill: '#5470c6',
            stroke: '#91cc75',
            highlightStyle: {
              fill: '#fac858',
            },
            valueAxisDomain: [0, 1],
            paddingOuter: 0,
            padding: {
              top: 0,
              bottom: 0,
            },
            axis: {
              strokeWidth: 0,
            },
          } ,
        },
      },
      {
        field: 'dispose',
        cellRenderer: 'agSparklineCellRenderer',
        cellRendererParams: {
          sparklineOptions: {
            type: 'bar',
            fill: '#5470c6',
            stroke: '#91cc75',
            highlightStyle: {
              fill: '#fac858',
            },
            valueAxisDomain: [0, 1],
            paddingOuter: 0,
            padding: {
              top: 0,
              bottom: 0,
            },
            axis: {
              strokeWidth: 0,
            },
          } ,
        },
      },
      {
        field: 'action',
        headerName: 'Action',
        sortable: true,
        resizable: true,
        filter: 
        true,
        cellRenderer: () => {
          return `
            <button mat-mini-fab="" color="warn" ptooltip="Action History" tooltipposition="top" class="mat-focus-indicator mat-mini-fab mat-button-base mat-primary" style="background-color: #7a1dcf;" ng-reflect-color="primary" ng-reflect-text="Action Detail" ng-reflect-tooltip-position="top"><span class="mat-button-wrapper"><i class="fa fa-list" style="color: #fff;"></i></span><span matripple="" class="mat-ripple mat-button-ripple mat-button-ripple-round" ng-reflect-disabled="false" ng-reflect-centered="false" ng-reflect-trigger="[object HTMLButtonElement]"></span><span class="mat-button-focus-overlay"></span></button>
            `;
        },
      },
    ],
  defaultColDef: {
    flex: 1,
    minWidth: 100,
    resizable: true,
  },
  rowData: getData(),
  rowHeight: 50,
};

// setup the grid after the page has finished loading
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  var gridDiv = document.querySelector('#myGrid');
  new agGrid.Grid(gridDiv, gridOptions);
});
```

Comment: Yes, I am using the enterprise version of ag-grid and I am trying to configure BarSparklines in angular 11, not in javascript

Comment: **My Angular front end code is:**

Comment: '<ag-grid-angular style="width: 100%; height: 30vw; margin-top:5px;" class="ag-theme-alpine"
          [columnDefs]="immediatecolumnDefs" [rowData]="immediaterowData" [rowHeight]="rowHeight"
          (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)" (cellClicked)='oncellclicked($event)' [pagination]="true">
        </ag-grid-angular>'

Comment: I don't know Angular, but I took the example plunker from AG Grid, plugged in your configuration and it rendered the bar charts. https://plnkr.co/edit/75Suvkmnql7PLWbz